# Can we say "to put the leash on the dog"? or Do we always have to say "to put the dog on the leash"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

People say "**Dogs must be kept on a lead (leash)**" in the dictionary.

> [**on**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/on) (prep)
>
> 5 ATTACHED attached to or hanging from something
>
> She hung her coat on a hook.
>
> Dogs must be kept on a lead (or leash) at all times.

The dictionary also says "**[It's as if somebody put June Cleaver's pearl necklace and apron on Madonna.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/necklace)**", so I reckon "**to put a necklace on somebody**" is a valid construction, thus I think "**to put the necklace on the dog**" is valid.

Now, a leash and a necklace look similar because both have a round piece that can be put around the dog neck except that a leash also has a long rope connecting to that round piece for the dog's owner to hold.

Say, now the dog is wearing nothing and you want to prepare for the dog for a walk.

Can we say "**to put the leash on the dog**" the same way we say "**to put the necklace on the dog**"?

But the dictionary says "**to keep the dog on the leash**" so I am not sure if we always have to say "**to put the dog on the leash**"?

**Very confusing?**

**Note**: we can say "**to put the collar on the dog**" but you can hook a rope with a hook to the collar and turn "**the collar & the rope**" to a thing that can be used like a leash. That is even **more confusing**.

Answer (score 1):

If you said you "put the leash on the dog" it would be understood to mean that you attached the leash to the dog's collar. It wouldn't imply that anybody kept hold of the other end of the leash.

If you "put the dog on the leash" it implies that somebody is holding the other end of the leash and using it to control the dog.

Comment: But I couldn't visualize how a leash looks like. Does a leash include a rope + a round piece or is a leash  a rope with a hook that can be hooked to a collar?

Comment: @Tom, If you buy it at the store, it normally has a hook to connect to a collar that the dog wears even when not leashed. If you make it ad hoc from a bit of rope, you might use part of the leash to form the collar.

Comment: In Britain, dogs are required to wear a collar (a strap round the neck) at all times. The collar has a metal ring attached. A lead or leash refers only to the strap or cord that you clip on to the ring when you want to take the dog for a walk.